# CEFSHARP Video player don't work on weibo.com site

Tags: chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I can not see the videos on the weibo.com website.

Debugging sees this error:
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

For example watch this link:
https://www.weibo.com/tv/v/FxU2CxqKj?from=vhot

What could be the problem?
Many thanks, 
Matteo

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

This means that some script tried to call the `play` method of a `video` object, but this was prevented by the browser, because this call was not directly related to a user interaction, that clearly indicates that the user *wants* the video to play at this point.

This is done to thwart attempts to autoplay videos without the user actually wanting this to happen - which can in the least be annoying, and at worst even costly (for example on a metered/mobile connection.)

But if this is not a problem you are experiencing with any code you have written yourself, then you can only ask the people behind this website to look into that for you - you’ll have to check what contact options or bug report possibilities they provide.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had also looked for the error detail on the internet and found the same explanation. But could you tell me why the video in the cefsharp component does not go? In chromium, chrome and firefox the video works correctly.

Comment: Such components that only embed part of a web browser’s functionality to be used somewhere else, can sometimes have issues like that, due to the fact _that_ they only implement parts of the functionality. Specifically in such a case as here, that ties directly into the browser UI, resp. how the user interacts with it (did they actually click somewhere before the play method for a video was called?), it is easily conceivable that this check does not function properly.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in cefsharp or is it a feature that will be added in the future?

Comment: HI Amaitland, can you contact me with email at info@zinformatica.net 
for a job request on cefsharp?